# How can I detect collision between QGraphicsItem and QGraphicsPixmapItem image from different classes

Tags: c++, qt, collision-detection, game-physics

I have QGraphicsEllipse items as bullets in a scene. Targets are QPixmap images and I want just the bullets and images to interact, NOT target on target collision. Bullets are created in my scene class and QPixmaps are created in my dialog class.

I tried adding a QList for the QPixmaps created similar to the QList QGraphicsItem * but don't think the compiler liked that. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
void Scene::advance()
{
        QList <QGraphicsItem *> itemsToRemove;
        foreach( QGraphicsItem * item, this->items())
        {

            if( !this->sceneRect().intersects(item->boundingRect()))
            {
                // The item is no longer in the scene rect, get ready to delete it
                itemsToRemove.append(item);
            }
        }

        foreach( QGraphicsItem * item, itemsToRemove )
        {
            this->removeItem(item);
            delete(item);
        }

        QGraphicsScene::advance();
}
```

BoundRect included in my MainTarget class

```
QRectF MainTargets::boundingRect() const
{
    qreal shift = 1;
        return QRectF(-w/2 -shift, - h/2
                      - shift, w + shift, h + shift);
}

QPainterPath MainTargets::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(boundingRect());
    return path;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
class GraphicsCircle : public QGraphicsRectItem
// class for the pellets
{
public:
    GraphicsCircle(qreal dirx, qreal diry)
        : m_Speed(5)
        , m_DirX(dirx)
        , m_DirY(diry)
    {
        setRect(-3.0,-3.0,8.0,8.0);
        setPos(-140, 195);
        QRadialGradient rGrad( 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        rGrad.setColorAt(0.0, QColor(255,255,255));
        rGrad.setColorAt(0.7, QColor(255,255,225));
        rGrad.setColorAt(1.0, QColor(255,0,0,0));
        setBrush(QBrush(rGrad) );
        setPen(QPen(Qt::NoPen));
    }

    virtual ~GraphicsCircle() {}

    void advance(int phase)
    {
        if(phase == 0) return;
        setPos(x()+m_Speed*m_DirX, y()+m_Speed*m_DirY);
    }

private:
    qreal m_Speed;
    qreal m_DirX;
    qreal m_DirY;
};
```

I changed my QPixmap object to QGraphicsPixmapItems. So back to the original problem of how to collide the pellets, QGraphicsItems, with targets, QGraphicsPixmapItems. I figured it would be some form of:

```
if(pellets->collidesWithItem(targets){
     remove(pellets)
     remove(targets)
 }
```

Comment: you're not OBLIGED to use QT `intersects` routine, you can detect the collision manually by using geometrical models.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of QPixmap, you can use QGraphicsPixmapItem and add the images to the graphics scene.

Also, you're calling intersects on the QGraphicsScene rect with the item's bounding Rect, which is in its local coordinate space: -

```
if( !this->sceneRect().intersects(item->boundingRect()))
```

Since these are in different coordinate spaces you need to convert the boundingRect to the scene's coordinate space before you compare

```
QRectF sceneBoundingRect = item->mapToScene(item->boundingRect);
```

Then use this for the comparison

```
if( !this->sceneRect().intersects(sceneBoundingRect))
```

Comment: Well they are already added to the scene. Just can't get the bullets and targets to interact.

Comment: Are you adding a QPixmap to the scene with scene->addWidget, or are you using QGraphicsPixmapItem?

Comment: I have an array of QPixmaps with .jpg's stored in them and select one randomly and `scene->addItem()`

Comment: QGraphicsScene::addItem takes a QGraphicsItem*. QPixmap cannot be passed to that function. Either you're using QGraphicsPixmap, or you're calling addWidget.

Comment: Yes, you are right I store the pictures into QPixmaps then store the index in a class that inherits from QGraphicsItem. `pmap = new MainTargets(main_targets[index], 1);` The MainTargets inherits from QGraphicsItem and is passed by reference. `scene->addItem(pmap)` But the Pixmap is added after the random Pixmap in the array is selected.

Comment: So, you create a new class that inherits QGraphicsItem. How do you handle the boundingRect function, which you need to overload here? If this is wrong, it would cause the collision to fail in the call to scene->intersects

Comment: All the boundingRect is handled in the MainTargets class. I provided the lines of code in the original post above.

Comment: If your shape is going to just return the bounding rect, you don't need to overload that; it's used for irregular shapes. I see the problem now. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: every where I try to add the line to convert local to scene coordinates an error occurs. Should that be added in the scene advance method or Maintargets class?

Comment: Where are you adding that line and what is the error?

Comment: I still have the original problem of not colliding the QPixmapsItems(targets) and the QGraphicsItems(pellets). I added the class for the pellets in original documentation to see. The problem is I have the pellets in one class and targets in another. One inheriting from QGraphicsRectItem and the other from QGraphicsScene respectively. Was thinking maybe have the pellet advance function collide with any target or pellet and disappear both colliding items ( when I tried that in the Scene advance function it only removes one of the colliding items not both).

Comment: "One inheriting from QGraphicsRectItem and the other from QGraphicsScene respectively" Neither the pellets nor the targets should be inheriting from QGraphicsScene. They are both QGraphicsItems.

Comment: Is there a way to remove and delete the collision items from within the QGraphicsItem class I have above. I just called collidingitems in the bullets advance method and hide both the pellet and target.